# How can I aggregate multiple DTMF keys with Voximplant?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, voximplant

I am able to dial one digit with DTMF by calling into Voximplant who is connected with DialogFlow. I have followed [this scenario](https://gist.github.com/chadwallacehart/c5071cad01aa670578c2c263c311d83c#file-voxengine_dialogflow_voicebot-js-L12), but as the code states in line 147, `// ToDo: aggregate multiple DTMF keys that are pressed in succession and send as a single string`.

Have anyone been able to dial inn more than one digit or could guide me to the correct example of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a more [comprehensive example](https://gist.github.com/chadwallacehart/cb6b0ffde81e604cb0c54cc7b7180e4b) for Voximplant that handles multiple DTMF entry. This requires a few extra parameters to control how many digits and when to stop collecting DTMF before reporting it back:

```
// Configurable via custom payload
let interToneTime = 3000               // Default time to wait for the next DTMF digit after one is pressed
let maxToneDigits = 12                 // Default number of DTMF digits to look for after one is pressed
let dtmfMode = "event"                 // Send DTMF key presses as events or as "text"
let stopTones = []                     // DTMF tones used to indicate end of digit entry
```

I then expanded on the original `onTone` function in the [DTMF example from cogint.ai](https://cogint.ai/voximplant-dialogflow-connector-2019/#dtmfdetection) you linked to:

```
function onTone(e) {
  Logger.write("DEBUG: onTone called: " + e.tone) // on iteration #" + cnt)

  if (stopTones.includes(e.tone)){
    Logger.write("DEBUG: stopTone entered: " + e.tone);
    toneTimerCallback()
    return
  }

  noInputTimer.stop()
  toneCount++;
  tones.push(e.tone)

  if (toneCount >= maxToneDigits){
    Logger.write("DEBUG: maximum number of specified tones reached: " + toneCount) // on iteration #" + cnt)
    toneTimerCallback()
  }
  else
    toneTimer.start()

}
```

This essentially pushes the tone into an array and calls the `toneTimerCallback` function if a stop tone is pressed (i.e. this is usually `#` or `*`) or if `maxToneDigits` is exceeded.

The `toneTimerCallback` just converts the digits to a string and sends them to Dialogflow:

```
function toneTimerCallback() {
  let toneString = tones.join('').toString()  // bug requires adding an extra .toString()
  
  if (toneString == '') {
    Logger.write("DEBUG: toneTimerCallback - invalid toneString: " + toneString)
    return
  }

  Logger.write("DEBUG: sending DTMF in " + dtmfMode + "mode : " + toneString)
  if (dtmfMode == "event")
    dialogflow.sendQuery({ event: { name: "DTMF", language_code: "en", parameters: { dtmf_digits: toneString } } })
  else if (dtmfMode == "text")
     dialogflow.sendQuery({ text: { text: toneString.toString(),  language_code: "en" }}) // bug requires adding an extra .toString()

  toneCount = 0
  tones = []
}
```

This shows how to send the digits as a text input or as an event.

Other related parts in the gist show how to set these parameters on a per-intent basis using custom payloads. This for example, could let you specify a max of 5 digits for a ZIP code in one intent and set 10 for another that asks for a phone number.